# eBay API - get large thumbnail images with findItemsIneBayStores call

Tags: json, ebay-api

Does anyone know how can I get larger images with `findItemsIneBayStores` API call? I use JSON response and my request is following:

```
http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?OPERATION-NAME=findItemsIneBayStores&SERVICE-VERSION=1.0.0&SECURITY-APPNAME=-DATA-FORMAT=JSON&REST-PAYLOAD&storeName=
```

Answer (score 0):

Found answer.. I needed to add

```
&outputSelector=PictureURLLarge
```

to api call url